# how to use an arbitrary function in a wrapper function in Python

Tags: python, function, wrapper, keyword-argument

I want to create a wrapper function something like the following:

```
def functionWrapper(function, **kwargs):
    """
        This function requires as input a function and a dictionary of named arguments for that function.
    """
    results=function(**kwargs)
        print results

def multiply(multiplicand1=0, multiplicand2=0):
    return multiplicand1*multiplicand2

def main():
    functionWrapper(
        multiply,
        {
            'multiplicand1': 3,
            'multiplicand2': 4,
        }
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am running into difficulties with this implementation:

```
TypeError: functionWrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

How should I address this problem? Is my use of the arbitrary function in the wrapper function `function(**kwargs)` reasonable? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: fixed error in specification of dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Use ** when passing the dict items to that function;

```
**{
   'multiplicand1': 3,
   'multiplicand2': 4,
  }
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

As pointed out by @svk in comments, `functionWrapper`'s doctstring says:

> This function requires as input a function and a dictionary of named
>   arguments for that function.

So in that case you need to change the function definition to:

```
def functionWrapper(function, kwargs):
```

and also fix the typo in the dict otherwise you'll get 0 as answer:

```
'multiplicand1': 3,
'multiplicand1': 4,  #Change this to 'multiplicand2
```

'

Comment: And note the change to `multiplicand2` for the 2nd multiplicand

Comment: This doesn't seem to be in line with the docstring for `functionWrapper`, which seems to say that `functionWrapper` should take two arguments: one callable and one dictionary, not a callable and an arbitrary number of keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `**kwargs` to `kwargs` in function defenition:

```
def functionWrapper(function, kwargs):
```

[What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the spirit of this question is begging for this answer as well, to make it a more general wrapper.

```
def functionWrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):

    results = func(*args, **kw)

    print results 

def multiply(multiplicand1=0, multiplicand2=0):
    return multiplicand1*multiplicand2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    functionWrapper(multiply, multiplicand1=3, multiplicand2=4)
    # 12

    functionWrapper(multiply, 3, 4)
    # 12

    functionWrapper(multiply, 3)
    # 0

    functionWrapper(multiply)
    # 0

    functionWrapper(multiply, 5, multiplicand2=4)
    # 20
```